# How to acess elements inside nested dictionary python

Tags: python

I am new to python and would really appreciate your help.
I have a JSON file containing Key value pairs .Basically I have to extract 'all_points_x' and 'all_points_y’ present inside ‘regions’.I have created a loop but I am not giving right key to extract ‘regions’.Kindly need your help in solving the issue.
json_data file contents

```
_via_img_metadata {'barley_Admixture_image28.jpg2218': {'filename': 'barley_Admixture_image28.jpg', 'size': 2218, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [35, 28, 27, 31, 40, 51, 62, 72, 74, 71, 65, 57, 41], 'all_points_y': [74, 55, 32, 16, 4, 6, 12, 35, 56, 74, 83, 86, 81]}, 'region_attributes': {}},

for i in range(len(json_data[keys]['regions'])):
            coords = []
            for j in range(len(json_data[keys]['regions'][i]['shape_attributes']['all_points_x'])):
                coords.append((json_data[keys]['regions'][i]['shape_attributes']['all_points_x'][j], json_data[keys]['regions'][i]['shape_attributes']['all_points_y'][j]))
            coords = np.asarray([coords], dtype=np.int32)
            if i == 0:
                mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
                cv2.polylines(mask, coords, isClosed=True, color=255, thickness=4)
            else:
                mask1 = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
                cv2.polylines(mask1, coords, isClosed=True, color=255, thickness=4)
                mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask,mask1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below to extract the all_points_x and all_points_y tuple, I have assumend your json as input_json:

```
input_keys = input_json.keys()
for key in input_keys:
    for obj in input_json[key]['regions']:
        for i in range(len(obj['shape_attributes']['all_points_x'])):
            coords.append((obj['shape_attributes']['all_points_x'][i], obj['shape_attributes']['all_points_y'][i]))
print(coords)
```

Comment: Getting error 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Would really appreciate your help.thank you very much

Comment: There is a 'None' element in the values which is causing the error.
{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [35, 28, 27, 31, 40, 51, 62, 72, 74, 71, 65, 57, 41], 'all_points_y': [74, 55, 32, 16, 4, 6, 12, 35, 56, 74, 83, 86, 81]}, 'region_attributes': {}}, None, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [6, 16, 24, 44, 69, 77, 81, 82, 80, 76, 69, 62, 51, 26, 9, 7], 'all_points_y': [85, 77, 78, 83, 92, 100, 106, 115, 118, 120, 122, 125, 126, 112, 98, 92]}, 'region_attributes': {}}]

Comment: Yes I was able to solve it by adding If condition to exclude None.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can access items in nested dictionary like this

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    for k,v in value.items()
        #do sth
```

As I understand your json_data below code should work.

```
coords = []

for key,value in json_data.items():
    regions = value['regions']
    for i in range(len(regions)):
        for x,y in zip(regions[i]['shape_attributes']['all_points_x'],regions[i]['shape_attributes']['all_points_y']):
            coords.append((x,y))
```

Comment: Getting error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. What does this mean?Where am I going worng? Any help please

Comment: There is a 'None' element in the values which is causing the error.

 {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [35, 28, 27, 31, 40, 51, 62, 72, 74, 71, 65, 57, 41], 'all_points_y': [74, 55, 32, 16, 4, 6, 12, 35, 56, 74, 83, 86, 81]}, 'region_attributes': {}}, None, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [6, 16, 24, 44, 69, 77, 81, 82, 80, 76, 69, 62, 51, 26, 9, 7], 'all_points_y': [85, 77, 78, 83, 92, 100, 106, 115, 118, 120, 122, 125, 126, 112, 98, 92]}, 'region_attributes': {}}]